# AdWords remarketing tag not detected

Tags: google-ads-api, google-tag-manager

We're running remarketing tags via GTM for 13 sites. 12 are working and validated but 1 site/tag is not being recognised even though the setup seems identical.

[Working](http://www.feriebolig-spania.no/) vs. [non-working](http://www.feriebolig-spanien.dk/). I think we've overlooked something small, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Probally not related, but are you aware that you are running multiple Analytics on those sites?